# Text for offering a free service and user engagement

Tags: copywriting, call-to-action

Which is the better text to use in an image banner for offering a free medical examination service on a website:

1. "Contact us for a free examination"

   OR
2. "Free examination, contact us for more information"

Basically I am between the two because the first engages the user to contact, however the second might attract more attention because of the "free" word that comes first.

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to UX! It's easier for us to help you if we know what kind of service you're trying to advertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Free evaluation" doesn't sound free at all to me.  There are many cases where the evaluation is free, but everything else isn't.  **What you mean by evaluation is vague**.

Think of the common example where you are offered a free photo shoot, but then afterwards if you want any of the photos, you have to pay.

I (as a picky consumer) would want a clearer picture of what it is before I waste my time on it.  So I would suggest making what you are offering clearer.  If you tell us exactly what you are offering, you will get better suggestions.

That said, you **don't need to include "contact us"** for people to know that they have to contact you to get it. Still, as always, **test it**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In order to describe the problem better, a free examination will be offered to test whether someone is liable for a surgery.

Comment: @mentalic: who performs the evaluation?  Doctor, program, etc.

Comment: The free examination is offered by a Doctor

Answer (score 1):

As @JohnGB, don't include "contact us", just make it clear what they have to do to get this. Use the space to explain more clearly what it is that people are signing up to.

And if this is banner advertising, you are not offering something for free. You are offering an inducement to pay for something, by providing a no-cost entry. The only people who believe that you can get something for free from a banner click are the ones who have very rich relatives they never knew about in Nigeria.

You will get more click throughs if you are clearer what you are offering, and how you are making your money for the ads. "Free initial examination" would be more honest. Of course, I am not a marketeer.

Answer (score 0):

Number 2 seems like the obvious choice.  You could draw attention to the contact us by making it a link?

Answer (score 0):

Try both. (Probably make some more copies) Stick with the one with the better conversion rate. And try to make variations of that one too. And again measure the conversion.